# Set Excel Pivot table with R

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, pivot, rpivottable

I want to make a pivot using R, set pivot table fields and export to Excel as formatted pivot table. Is there any package that allows me to do this? Maybe it is possible to first set a pivot table with excel and then use R to read and export other tables?

Comment: Almost everything is possible in R. But one important condition is to provide a minimal reproducible example <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)>

Comment: You could try using `rpivotTable`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many packages that help you make pivot tables, the most popular are `Tidyr` from `Tidyverse` and `data.table`, and to export to Excel you can use `XLConnect` or `openxlsx`. Maybe if you provide some reproducible example someone around here could help you.